# I don't know hot to plot this nonlp's feasible reagion in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, constraints, nonlinear-functions

I searched and watched how to plot the 3 dimensions of nonlp program's

but I still don't know how to plot these constraints.

x^2+y^2+z^2=1

x>=2*y
2*y>=3*z
x>=3*z

I programmed like this but it doesn't work and I think this is wrong program for upper constraints.

```
func1 = @(x,y,z) sqrt(1-x.^2-y.^2);
func2 = @(x,y,z) max(x-2*y,0);
func3 = @(x,z) max(x-3*z,0);
ezsurf(func1,[0 1 0 1]);
hold on;
ezsurf(func2,[0 1 0 1]);
hold on;
ezsurf(func3,[0 1 0 1]);
axis([0 1 0 1 0 1]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A way of doing that is to work with volumetric data.

The idea is to create a 3D space, with a `F` value. `F` will be positive in one side of your main equation and negative in the other.

```
[X,Y,Z]=meshgrid(-2:0.05:2,-2:0.05:2,-2:0.05:2);

F=X.^2+Y.^2+Z.^2-1;
```

Then the conditions are applied to this `F`. If you want to see the object "cut"
then substitute the place where conditions are not met with `nan`. If you want to see a filled object, then substitute it with a positive number (it may need to be negative in another situation, so check this for other examples.

```
% Conditions
cond1=X>=2*Y;
cond2=2*Y>=3*Z;
cond3=X>=3*Z;

% If you want the boundaries to show
F1=F;
F1(~cond1)=1;
F1(~cond2)=1;
F1(~cond3)=1;

% If you want the boundaries not to show
F2=F;
F2(~cond1)=NaN;
F2(~cond2)=NaN;
F2(~cond3)=NaN;
```

Then the idea is to create an isosurface in the zero level (your original function). Here in this code I created 2 plots so you can see the differences between filling and not filling the boundaries. Also some fancy coding in order to get nice figures. However the `isosurface` and `patch`  parts are relevant to obtain the surface and plot it.

```
subplot(121)
iso1=isosurface(X,Y,Z,F1,0);
p=patch(iso1);
isonormals(X,Y,Z,F1,p);
set(p,'FaceColor','red','EdgeColor','none');
daspect([1 1 1])
axis equal

camlight
lighting gouraud


subplot(122)
iso2=isosurface(X,Y,Z,F2,0);

p=patch(iso2);
isonormals(X,Y,Z,F2,p);
set(p,'FaceColor','red','EdgeColor','none');
axis equal

daspect([1 1 1])
camlight headlight
lighting gouraud
```

Result:

[image]

Additionally, You can calculate the isosurface of the initial boundary `F` and plot it with a low alpha value, so you can better understand what piece of the domain you are actually selecting.

[image]

Comment: @rayryeng Thanks :D If there is something I most love about Matlab is the plotting possibilities, and this is just for pre-2014b!

Comment: Nice :) I'm still using R2013a because this is right at the tail end when things change significantly if you go to the next version after this and I want to provide solutions that generally work for everybody.  If I migrated to R2014+, I would rely on a lot of new functions to help me solve questions when many may not have access to those functions.  Basically, if I try and do `help <function>` and if I don't have it on my version of MATLAB, I won't use it for my answer and that probably means that a lot of other people won't have it either and so I won't use that in my solution.

Comment: @rayryeng Makes a lot of sense. As currently I am in academia, where if the code is legible means that you spent too much time on it (never happens) , I just use whatever the heck I want XD

Comment: Thanks for your help. I solved with your answer. Thanks again!

Comment: @김종현 No problem! Do not forget to accept the answer if it helped!

Comment: @AnderBiguri If I want to plot something like this? $\Omega = $

Comment: @roni I am quite sure " $\Omega = $" is not an equation that can be plotted

Comment: @AnderBiguri Sorry about that. The complete problem which I want to plot is this. f(x)=x2 constraint set is O = {x : x1^2+x2^2>=1}. What is the best way to show such a plot ?